# Strapi query by unique field

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi

I am getting started with Strapi and have setup a basic model in the Strapi admin called `page` which looks like so:

```
page: {
  title: Text (required)
  slug: Text (required and unique)
}
```

As you can see it has a field called `slug` which is always unique. What I am wondering is how I can query by this field?

So far I have added 1 entry and when I launch graphql playground (at http://localhost:1337/graphql) I can get my entry returned via the following query:

```
query {
  page(id:"1") {
    title
  }
}
```

When I try to query via `slug` as opposed to `id` like so:

```
query {
  page(slug:"/") {
    title
  }
}
```

I am unable to do so even though it's a unique field. It does not even come up with the suggestions to use `slug` as a unique idetifier input inside the brackets. Why would this be?

Comment: If I read [this](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/graphql.html#query-api) correctly, you have to do something like `page(where: { slug_contains: "/" })`

Comment: Strangely tha works for the `pages` type that queries many but trying to use `where` on the `page` type does not come up as an option

Comment: So trying as I suggested works, but the recommendation-feature / autocomplete does not work? If so, then the problem is most likely in the editor and not in your code

Comment: No I am not referring to the recommendation feature, adding the where object when dealing with single instances like `user` or `page` as opposed to `users` or `pages` does not work.

Comment: Your recommendation did not work until I changed `page` to `pages`

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the generated schema. I guess single instances only have the id field as parameter

Comment: That's right they do but this seems like an odd API design if that's the case, was wondering if something in my config was perhaps not correct

Comment: Well, `page` only returns one element - and what better option is there to ensure only one will return? The answer is to use an id, because they should be unique. If you need to query by different parameters you can still use `pages`, which, depending on the query, may give you only one result too

Comment: It is not that simple when you need to query by the slug that's in the router and the FE is unaware what the ID is. I can use `pages` but it seems like a hack to do so